# WCF in ASP.NET can't use State Server

Tags: asp.net, wcf, cookies

I'm hosting a WCF service within ASP.NET. The WCF service requires a cookie for most operations. It works fine if ASP.NET session state is "InProc". However, we want to move the app to a web farm & I'd like to run the State Service on a dedicated machine. When I do this, the WCF methods do not generate the cookie.

Any ideas?

Code to add the cookie:

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.SetCookie] = "myCookie" + MyVal.ToString();
```

WCF configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>

<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="secure">
      <security mode="Transport" />          
    </binding>
    <binding name="basic"></binding>                 
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<services>
  <service name="MyService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MyService.Interface" behaviorConfiguration="web" bindingConfiguration="secure" />

    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MyService.Interface" behaviorConfiguration="web" bindingConfiguration="basic" />
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" httpHelpPageEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>

  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" faultExceptionEnabled="true" defaultBodyStyle="Bare" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
```

Comment: I am guessing you already have following set for your service?
`<AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode:=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)> _`

Comment: Yes - I have that in the service.